# Why is Python requests.session() aborting connection?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the requests lib in a python project to get information from a site.

```
    @classmethod
def get_query(cls, url):
    """
    Getter method for retrieving information from exchange in the form of json
    :param url: specific path to follow base_rul for individualised requests
    :return: json object containing information sent by the API as per the request
    """
    base_url = 'https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/'  # URL FOR THE EXCHANGE
    json = cls.session.get(base_url + url, timeout=5).json()  # fetches data from API
    return json
```

I was able to make over 500 get-requests before getting this error:

**`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10051, 'WSAENETUNREACH')"))`**

In the docs they mention a "keep alive" attribute however they don't show it's usage in requests.session()

Comment: Are you hitting the api rate limit?

Comment: I'm not. the limit is above 100 requests/second. I'm only making 1. The API docs mention a "Keep-Alive directive" but don't show how its implemented.[Link to API Here](https://api.hitbtc.com/)

Comment: If you are using Http 1.1 then keep alive is automatically handled by it. Otherwise keep alive needs to be implemented explicitly. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Requests python package and creating a Session object. The docs mention that 'keep-alive is 100% automatic within a session'. I think the error might have been due to an internet drop or power cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue might just be that my laptop is going to sleep.

I could put the code on a server or my Raspberry-Pi to solve this problem.